# Python не подцепает устройство измерения Agilent B1500 по GPIB

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт, gpio

Пытаюсь провести измерения с помощью Agilent B1500, написав код в python, используя библиотеку pymeasure 0.9.0.

Проверка подключенных к компьютеру устройств:

```
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
print (rm.list_resources())
```

Выполняется и выдает:
`('GPIB0::10::INSTR', 'GPIB0::22::INSTR', 'GPIB0::28::INSTR')`

По адресу `'GPIB0::10::INSTR'` и находится мой Agilent B1500.
Импортируя библиотеку и присваивая значение:

```
from pymeasure.instruments.agilent import agilentB1500
b1500 = agilentB1500("GPIB0::10::INSTR", read_termination='\r\n', write_termination='\r\n', timeout=100000)
```

Появляется ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 11, in <module>
    b1500 = agilentB1500("GPIB0::10::INSTR", read_termination='\r\n', write_termination='\r\n', timeout=100000)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Подскажите как побороть данную ошибку...

Мой файл `agilentB1500.py` находится по адресу `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\pymeasure\instruments\agilent`

Версия установленных модулей:

```
importlib-metadata==4.0.1
numpy==1.20.2
pandas==1.2.4
PyMeasure==0.9.0
pyqtgraph==0.12.1
pyserial==3.5
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2021.1
PyVISA==1.11.3
six==1.15.0
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
zipp==3.4.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этой строке `from pymeasure.instruments.agilent import agilentB1500` объект `agilentB1500` является модулем, потому что в пакете `agilent/` есть `agilentB1500.py`. Но в файле `__init__py` пакета `agilent/` уже есть [импорт класса AgilentB1500](https://github.com/pymeasure/pymeasure/blob/ba4d002f416bd24dcaa97538527ed514c9f14f7c/pymeasure/instruments/agilent/__init__.py#L35), поэтому можно из пакета сделать импорт класса (пример ниже из документации):

```
...
from .agilentB1500 import AgilentB1500
```

[Из примера документации](https://pymeasure.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/instruments/agilent/agilentB1500.html#initialization-of-the-instrument) импорт должен быть такой:

```
from pymeasure.instruments.agilent import AgilentB1500
```

Тогда:

```
b1500 = AgilentB1500("GPIB0::10::INSTR", read_termination='\r\n', write_termination='\r\n', timeout=100000)
```

**PS.**

А так, можно импортировать самостоятельно напрямую из модуля:

```
from pymeasure.instruments.agilent.agilentB1500 import AgilentB1500
```

Comment: Теперь 
`in _data_formatting
    "so far.").format(output_format_str)
NotImplementedError: Data Format FMT13 is not implemented so far`. 
Видно придется ждать обновления.

Comment: @DenMolib, ну да, эту ошибку оставил сам разработчик, вы можете тут отслеживать исправления и доработки: https://github.com/pymeasure/pymeasure/issues